# Spring Data Repository: "Containing" for Collections

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, repository

I'm looking for a Spring Data method to fetch an entity by checking if a property (a Set) contains an element. Here an example:

Entity `User`:

- `Long` id
- `Set<Location>` locations

Spring Data Repository for `User`:

```
Set<User> findAllByLocationsContaining(Location location);
```

---

The above mentioned example works, but it is not documented in the documentation. Is is only documented for String comparisons with `LIKE`. Is there a recommended way to create a query in that scenario? (see [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation))

---

**EDIT:** As a workaround, I'm using in the meantime the following custom query:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.locations l WHERE :location IN l")
public Set<User> findAllByLocationsContaining(@Param("location") Location location);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use simply an `Equals` as you are looking for the set to contain a certain instance:

```
Set<User> findAllByLocationsEquals(Location location);
```

or

```
Set<User> findAllByLocationsIdEquals(Integer locationId);
```